# Bing Maps PushPin Error

Tags: vb.net, bing-maps, pushpin

Hello I'm trying to determine my pushpin by the latitude and longitude but for some reason I get a error line under latitude   **Pushpin(latitude, longitude)** my map is happy to center using the same code if I just change Pushpin to Location but I don't understand why it won't work with Pushpin?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim latitude As Double = Double.Parse(TXTLAT.Text.Substring(0, TXTLAT.Text.IndexOf(","c)))
    Dim longitude As Double = Double.Parse(TXTLong.Text.Substring(TXTLong.Text.IndexOf(","c) + 1))


    UserControl11.BingMap.Center = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin(latitude, longitude)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the map you need to pass in a Location object, not a Pushpin. A Pushpin is a UIElement that gets displayed on top of the map, where as the center property is the position of the map. If you want to center the map on a location and also display a pushpin there do the following:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim latitude As Double = Double.Parse(TXTLAT.Text.Substring(0, TXTLAT.Text.IndexOf(","c)))
    Dim longitude As Double = Double.Parse(TXTLong.Text.Substring(TXTLong.Text.IndexOf(","c) + 1))

    Dim location = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Location(latitude, longitude)

    Dim Pin = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()
    pin.Location = location

    UserControl11.BingMap.Center = location
End Sub
```

You can find complete documentation on the Bing Maps WPF control here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx

Comment: Hello and thanks for responding my code now goes to the location but for some reason I still don't get a push pin when using             Dim Pin = New Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF.Pushpin()
    pin.Location = location

Comment: You have to add it to the map. Do something like MyMap.Children.Add(pin);

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly, sorry to be a pain but you might know currently as you can see I have set it up to look at my txtlat and txtlong for coordinates which Is being populated by a data base and data source connected is it possible to map all of my locations with pushpins when the application is loaded? e.g. places one push pin in London location, one in edinburgh and so on for each.

Comment: Yes, simply loop through your data and create a new pushpin object. However, if you have a thousands of locations you may want to consider other optimizations such as clustering, or only loading in data for certain areas as needed.

Comment: Hello thanks for your previous answer, how would I add a loop through my data to plot all of my points at once, I want to use a simple button click to display 20 at once.

Comment: Use a loop to go through your data, create pushpins and add them to the map using the Map.Children.Add property.